# insert the value after checking duplidate key

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert `CONTENT_VALUES` if `survey_Id` is not existing in the table.If that value is existing I want to update `CONTENT_VALUES` for the `SURVEY_ID`.

```
$sql="insert into `$prefix.survey_question`  (SURVEY_ID, CONTENT_VALUES, USER_ID, CREATED_ON)values('$sur_id','$content_val','$email','$now') on duplicate key update CONTENT_VALUES=values('$content_val')";
     $query1=mysql_query($sql)
```

Comment: What's `$query1=mysql_query("CONTENT_VALUES")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove a speech mark on the values set, and correct the `CONTENT_VALUES` update, and fire the query correctly:

```
$query1= "insert into `$prefix.survey_question`  
   (SURVEY_ID, CONTENT_VALUES, USER_ID, CREATED_ON)
values
   ('$sur_id','$content_val','$email','$now') 
on duplicate key 
update CONTENT_VALUES=('$content_val'), 
       USER_ID = '$email', 
       CREATED_ON = '$now'";
     $resultset=mysql_query($query1);
```

Also look into using `PDO` over `mysql` extension.

Comment: alues are inserted again

Comment: You need to set up `SURVEY_ID` as a primary key in order to fire the on duplicate key update, otherwise no duplicate key exists, and it will insert again.

Comment: `alter table $prefix.survey_question add primary key (SURVEY_ID)`

Comment: my table 'A'  have fields survey_id is primary key. In my survey_question table Id is primary key

Comment: `alter table $prefix.survey_question
  add unique index SURVEY_KEY(SURVEY_ID)`

Comment: ^Try adding a unique index on `SURVEY_ID`. Its not the primary key so it needs to have unique values in order for your on duplicate to fire

Answer (score 0):

you can use insert ignore query,  if inserted record is duplicate then query result will be zero then go ahead with update.